# Is there any difference between the two handbrake options?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I notice that, on Xbox at least, both <kbd>RB</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> are assigned to handbrake. I had a look at the controls and noticed that <kbd>A</kbd> is also used for answering the phone in the vehicle, so my question: is there any difference between the two handbrakes? I know on a bike there is additional braking controls (different buttons for front and back brakes) but presumably this is not the case in a car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/51371/the-free-gtav-ifruit-and-game-manual-companion-apps.html), there is no difference.

<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>RB</kbd> buttons are both mapped to the handbrake, so it's just for convenience.

Personally, I alternate between the two based on what I am doing.

**Example:**

When I want to change weapons, <kbd>X</kbd>, and make an immediate sharp turn, I would use <kbd>A</kbd>.

Otherwise, I would use <kbd>RB</kbd> *(especially if I had to answer the phone)*.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

i think that rb is for making weaker powerslide like drifts making a lil turn or something while the a handbrake is slicker and stronger turning making good powerslides and pulling off the drifts

Comment: Hi Dee!  Would you have any other information that would help pad out your theory?